# Swagger generated API does not have return value

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen, swagger-editor

I am using swagger-codegen-3.0.0.

As shown below, the API specification has responses 200 and 400; however, when the addTeam() API is generated, it is generated with the return type 'void'.

I want to handle the response code 200 and/or 400. Does it mean I have explicitly, define the payload type in the response specification? Can someone please provide more details on how my 'responses' specification should be?

```
 49   /team:
 50     post:                                                                                           
 51       summary: Add team                                                                           
 52       operationId: addTeam                                                                        
 53       requestBody:                                                                                  
 54         description: Team detail being added                                                      
 55         content:                                                                                    
 56           application/json:                                                                         
 57             schema:                                                                                 
 58               type: array                                                                           
 59               items:                                                                                
 60                 $ref: "#/components/schemas/addTeamPayload"                                                                           
 61       responses:                                                                                    
 62         200:                                                                                        
 63           description: Ok                                                                           
 64         400:                                                                                        
 65           description: Bad request                                                                  
 66       tags:                                                                                         
 67         - Team
```

java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.0.jar generate -i teamApiSpec.yaml -l java --additional-properties jackson=true --artifact-id swagger-java-client-api

This command generates the below Java code/APIs.

```
/**
 * Add team
 * 
 * @param body Team detail being added (optional)
 * @throws ApiException If fail to call the API, e.g. server error or cannot deserialize the response body

 */
public void addTeam(List<AddTeamPayload> body) throws ApiException {
    addTeamWithHttpInfo(body);
}

/**
 * Add Team
 * 
 * @param body Team detail being added (optional)
 * @return ApiResponse&lt;Void&gt;
 * @throws ApiException If fail to call the API, e.g. server error or cannot deserialize the response body

 */
public ApiResponse<Void> addTeamWithHttpInfo(List<AddTeamPayload> body) throws ApiException {
    com.squareup.okhttp.Call call = addTeamValidateBeforeCall(body, null, null);
    return apiClient.execute(call);
}
```

Another issue is even though 400 response code is programmed in the API spec, when server returns 400, the API still throws an exception and in process, the return code details are lost. As a user of the API, I do not know what return code is returned or what return response message is sent by the server.

Can someone please comment on this? This is important. Let me know if I have missed something in my API spec.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a content description to your responses if your service returns data.

```
  /team:
     post:                                                                                           
       summary: Add team                                                                           
       requestBody:                                                                                  
         description: Team detail being added                                                      
         content:                                                                                    
           application/json:                                                                         
             schema:                                                                                 
               type: array                                                                           
               items:
                 $ref: '#/components/schemas/addTeamPayLoad'
       responses:                                                                                    
         200:                                                                                        
           description: Ok
           content:
             '*/*':
              schema:
                type: object
         400:                                                                                        
           description: Bad request
           content:
             '*/*':
              schema:
                type: object
       tags:                                                                                         
         - Team
```

Comment: But what happens when I do that, because I've tried and not seeing an improvement. What happens when the 400 is returned?

Comment: Did you add a content section to every response type?

Comment: I think the issue relates more to Swagger Codegen, for non 2xx responses you get an exception containing a String, rather than an object corresponding to the schema type. I have worked around it and moved on.